# Save processes in cache and save at once in a text file

Tags: php

I use the following code to get the size of the files in a folder. As you can see, to save the size of a file in a text file, you have to open and close the text file from the hard drive each time. I want to first store all the information in cache (RAM) and then at once in a text file. Do you think this will speed things up? Do you have an idea and code to do this?

```
<?php 
$dir = 'img/';
foreach (glob($dir."*.png") as $filename) {
    $filesize = 'File Size: '.round((filesize($filename)/1024/1024),2).' MB';
    echo $filesize."</br>";
    fwrite(fopen("result.txt", "a"), $filesize."\n");
    fclose("result.txt");
}
?>
```

Comment: If you're worried about file IO, then just append each file size to a string and save it after the loop, or store them in an array and either implode it or store it as json after the loop. Unless you do this often, have huge list of files, or read the file often at the same time as your doing this, I doubt it will have any noticeable effect. _Side note:_  An easier way would be to use [file_put_contents()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.file-put-contents.php) (it's the same as fopen/fwrite/fclose, but with only one function call).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php 
$dir = 'img/';
$result='';
foreach (glob($dir."*.png") as $filename)
{
    $filesize = 'File Size: '.round((filesize($filename)/1024/1024),2).' MB';
    echo $filesize."</br>";
    $result.=$filesize."\n";
}
fwrite(fopen("result.txt", "a"), $result."\n");
fclose("result.txt");
?>
```

This way you saving all content to `$result` and write content to file once after all sizes checked.